# Multiple select url parameter redirects

Tags: jquery, select

I have two select boxes, one for city and another one for color.
What i want to achieve is when you select any option from ANY dropdown it would redirect to url http://domain.com/?city=CITY&color=COLOR

At first I was using this approach:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function change_url(val) {
        window.location=val;
    }
</script>            
<select id="city" onchange="change_url(this.value);">
   <option value="http://domain.com/?city=newyork">New York</option>
   <option value="http://domain.com/?city=paris">Paris</option>
</select>
```

This works perfectly if i have only one select box, but in this case I want to pass multiple select boxes values to url and i DON'T want to use submit button for this!

How should i change this code?

```
<select id="city">
   <option value="newyork">New York</option>
   <option value="paris">Paris</option>
</select>

<select id="color">
   <option value="blue">Blue</option>
   <option value="red">Red</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/mayanksaxena19/8xpwohn8/)

**javacript**

```
function change_url(city,color) {
        var baseURL = 'http://domain.com/?city=' + city + '&color=' + color;
        window.location=baseURL;
        //alert(baseURL);
}

$(function(){
        $('#city, #color').change(function(){ // attaching a handler to city and color dropdown list on Change
             change_url($('#city').val(),$('#color').val());
        });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<select id="city">
   <option value="newyork">New York</option>
   <option value="paris">Paris</option>
</select>

<select id="color">
   <option value="blue">Blue</option>
   <option value="red">Red</option>
</select>
```

Hope this works for you

Comment: Thanks Manyank! With alert it works perfectly, but with uncommented "window.location=val" it doesn't do anything :(

Comment: **baseURL** variable will hold the updated URL as per your current selection. I have updated the javascript code as per your requirement

Comment: Yeah now it works :) Thank you very much for helping!

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function change_url(val) {
        //you can use document.getElementById instead of jquery's api
        var url = "";
        var color = $("#city").value();   
        url += ("city=" + val + "&color=" + color)
        window.location=url;
    }
</script>            
<select id="city" onchange="change_url(this.value);">
   <option value="http://domain.com/?city=newyork">New York</option>
   <option value="http://domain.com/?city=paris">Paris</option>
</select>

<select id="color">
   <option value="blue">Blue</option>
   <option value="red">Red</option>
</select>
```